# What is the cocoa solids percentage of Hershey's semi-sweet chips?

Tags: chocolate

What is the percentage of cocoa solids in Hershey's semi-sweet chocolate chips?  Need to use it for a recipe that calls for 70-72% Cocoa solids.

Comment: You cannot just melt chocolate chips and use them in a recipe that calls for chocolate of a given percentage, even if it is the same percentage as in the chips! Chocolate chips have additives which totally change their melting behavior, so they won't work the same way chocolate does.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe any chocolate chips are going to have that high a percentage of cacao solids. According to [Cook's Illustrated](https://www.cooksillustrated.com/taste_tests/461-dark-chocolate-chips) the percentage of cacao solids in Hershey's semi-sweet chips is 42%. Hershey's Special Dark chips came in at 45%. Of all the bitter-sweet and semi-sweet chips they tested 60% was the highest amount listed (in Ghirardelli 60% Cacao Bittersweet Chocolate Chips).

Comment: Guittard makes 63% chips I think, but yeah, 70% is pretty high for chocolate chips, and Hershey's is nowhere near the high end.

Comment: Equal Exchange dark chocolate chips are 70%.